# Clang doesn't support the Lock Prefix. How shall I workaround?

Tags: c++, assembly, inline-assembly, clang

Assume this code:

```
  static inline void inc(int64_t* atomic)
  {
    __asm__ __volatile__
    (
      "lock incq %0\n"
        : "=m" (*atomic)
        : "m" (*atomic)
    );
  }
```

The Clang compiler doesn't support the lock prefix (yet?). What shall I do now?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not use the built-ins...?

```
static inlint void inc(int64_t* atomic) {
   __sync_add_and_fetch_8(atomic, 1);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

The integrated assembler doesn't understand prefixes which aren't separate statements yet. As a workaround, you can also just add a ';' after "lock". But as the other comment notes, you are better off using built-ins whenever possible.